# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered - Xamarin BoundServiceDemo crash

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, mono, xamarin.android

I had an issue with my existing Bound Service losing its Binder properties (The binder becomes disposed for some reason). So I went back a step and relearn the Bound Servcie. I downloaded the BoundServiceDemo application from Xamarin from the following page:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_2_-_bound_services/

The project built and run. But I noticed that if I do a sequence of `Unbind from service` and `Bind to service`(via button clicks in the project), the third `stop` will crash CONSISTENTLY. Pressing `Get timestamp from service` after binding to the service does not prevent the crash from happening. The stack trace is as follows:

> 05-23 10:33:21.334 11788 11788 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.xamarin.xample.boundservicedemo, PID: 11788
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:
>   md57edca57e0b6c066e67883d386d06086f.TimestampServiceConnection@37c0e
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1156)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1452)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native
>   Method)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344 11788 11788 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.344  4699  4724 W VirtualScreenManagerService:
>   moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): top activity or app is null
>
> 05-23 10:33:21.354  4699  4724 D InputDispatcher: Focused application
>   set to: xxxx

I am using VS2015 with Xamarin version 4.5.0.443. I hope this is not a bug with Xamarin because my application does multiple bind/unbind service during its lifetime. Can someone please shed some light? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the author of the sample code, Tom Opgenorth, and he believes that it is the dynamic setting of event handler for Click event that causes the crash. The event handler has now been modified to be registered once when the activity starts. It has fixed the issue.

Following Tom's information, I found that the event handler for RestartServiceButton click was registered every time the stop service button click but did not get unregistered until the application stopped. It means that RestartServiceButton click event would fire multiple times for each subsequent click. So the issue can also be resolved by unregistering itself from the event when it fires

```
void RestartServiceButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    restartServiceButton.Click -= RestartServiceButton_Click;
}
```

Tom should be uploading the updated version soon